# Binding error with thymeleaf , AJAX , th:object and Th:fragment

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, thymeleaf

I have a controller , i have a HTML view and i JS file.

In my HTML  file there´s a form , when i write the first parameter of this form Java Script detects the unfocus (blur)  and starts an AJAX call,  this AJAX call goes to SAP and returns the information of a user.  (I´m sure there´s no problem with the SAP remote call).

So... when we recieve the user information i try to write all that info in the respective fields of the html form,  that is the moment where i recieve **Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'ename' available as request attribute**

In the HTML FORM i have a **th:object**   and for each  i have a **th:field**, that´s the attribute with the problem.

If i delete all the **th:field**  the information gots written correctly but obviously the form post , wont have the required information.

---

Here´s my HTML Form

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/usuarios/addusuario}"
                        th:object="${usuarioModel}" method="post" >

                        <p>
                            Numero de Personal<input type="number" th:field="*{pernr}"
                                id="pernr" class="form-control" />
                        </p>
                        <div th:fragment="empleadoCarga" id="empleadoCarga">
                        <p>
                            Nombre Empleado<input type="text" th:field="*{ename}"
                                th:value="${empleado.enamep}" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            Correo Electronico<input type="text"  th:field="*{correo}"
                                th:value="${empleado.correoEmpleadop}" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
                        </p>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            ***  Sub Área a la que pertenece. ***
                            <select th:field="*{id_area}"
                                th:value="${id_area}" class="select2">
                                <option th:each="superPortalAreaObject : ${listaAreas}"
                                    th:value="${superPortalAreaObject.idArea}"
                                    th:text="${superPortalAreaObject.nombre}"></option>
                            </select>
                        </p>

                        <!--  <p>Ultimo Acceso<input type="Date" th:field="*{ultimo_acceso}" th:value="${ultimo_acceso}" class="form-control"/> </p>-->

                        <p>
                            Password<input type="text" th:field="*{ename}"
                                th:value="${password}" class="form-control" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{aplicacion}"  th:value="${1}"
                                class="form-control" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"
                                class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" />
                        </p>

                    </form>
```

Here´s my controller when the template is first shown (This is not crasshing)

```
@GetMapping("/listarusuario")
    public String listAllUsuario(@RequestParam(name = "id", required = false) int id, Model model) {
        LOG.info("Llamado a listarUsuario() creacion de usuarios");
        UsuarioModel usuario = new UsuarioModel();
        List<SuperPortalAreaObject> listaAreas = areaServiceImpl.listAllHijos();
        if (id != 0) {
            usuario = usuarioService.findUsuarioByPernrModel(id);
        }

        EmpleadosAutollenarModel empleado = new EmpleadosAutollenarModel();
        model.addAttribute("empleado", empleado);
        model.addAttribute("usuarioModel", usuario);
        model.addAttribute("listaAreas", listaAreas);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername());

        return ViewConstant.CREAR_USUARIO;
    }// fin listar usuario
```

And this is the code fragment that hears the AJAX call

```
    @GetMapping("/cargarEmpleado/{numEmpleado}")
    public String cargarEmpleado(Model model, @PathVariable("numEmpleado") String numEmpleado) {
//      List<EmpleadosAutollenarModel> listaResultadosEmpleadoAutollenar = null;
        EmpleadosAutollenarModel empleado = new EmpleadosAutollenarModel();
//      try {
//          final JCoDestination destinoSap = CONEXION_SAP.getDestinoSAP();
//          final JCoFunction funcionSap = CONEXION_SAP.crearFuncion(BAPI, destinoSap);
//          funcionSap.getImportParameterList().setValue("EMPLEADO", numEmpleado);
//          CONEXION_SAP.ejecutarBAPI(funcionSap, destinoSap);
//          if (funcionSap.getTableParameterList() != null) {
//              converter = new PortalComercialEmpleadosConverter();
//              LOG.info(funcionSap.getTableParameterList().getTable(0));
//              List<EmpleadosAutollenarModel> listaEmpleados = converter.convert(funcionSap.getTableParameterList().getTable(0));
//              // LOG.info(listaFacturas.size() + " resultados convertidos a
//              // DATA");
//              empleado = listaEmpleados.get(0);
//              LOG.info(empleado);
//          } else {
//              LOG.error("No se obtuvieron resultados");
//          } // Fin de else
//
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//          LOG.error("ERROR EN SAP DETALLES "+e.getCause().getMessage());
//      }
        UsuarioModel usuario = new UsuarioModel();
        model.addAttribute("usuarioModel", usuario);
        model.addAttribute("empleado", empleado);

        return "crearUsuario :: empleadoCarga";
    }// fin cargarEmpleado
```

i commented every part of the code that is SAP related ,  in order to decrease confusion, even with those lines commented the error still happen.

JAVA SCRIPT

```
$("#pernr").blur(function(e) {

        var value = $(this).val();
        var url = '/usuarios/cargarEmpleado/' + value;
//      $("#resultsBlockDetalle").load(url).then(detalle);

        loadurl(url).then(detalle);
//      detalleFinal()
    });

    var loadurl = function(url){
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        $("#empleadoCarga").load(url);

        setTimeout(function() {
            defer.resolve(); // When this fires, the code in a().then(/..../); is executed.
        }, 300);

        return defer;
    }
```

Comment: Check your empleado object for variable ename along with getter and setters.

Comment: Prior to the AJAX this form was working correctly, if i write all all the parameters manually and push the post button, it works as expected.

But when i try to auto write information to this form , the exception is thrown,  any idea?  what should i double check in the model?  any ways il start checking it as you suggest. :)

Comment: Ok i just checked your suggestion in my model i have the proper attributes/setter/getter also constructor that share name with those in the html file  (empleado.attribute) problem occurs with th:field="*{ename}" & th:field=*{correo}  that is related with th:object at the beggining of the form  :)